# python datetime.strptime [0-23] vs [1-24]

Tags: python, datetime

I am currently working with datetime.strptime. 
My input file have the date format for hours as [1-24]. Here a small example:

```
2015-05-10 21:00,1.209,1.239
2015-05-10 22:00,1.148,1.174
2015-05-10 23:00,1.093,1.117
2015-05-10 24:00,1.044,1.065
```

As far I have understood from the datetime.strptime works only with [0-23] format. Indeed the option is: %H as a zero-padded decimal number or %-H as a decimal number.

Am I right?
in this case, how can work with my data?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(fname2read,delimiter=',',header=0,parse_dates=True,\
                  na_values=-999)

df['datatime'] = df['datatime'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x),\
                 "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

Really Really thanks,
Diedro

Comment: Where is "1-24" a "format"…? How do you represent the time one minute past midnight?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you give an example of your code?

Comment: @deceze 24:00 on day 0 is a synonym for 00:00 on day 1.  Not common but not impossible either. It is an analogue of the 12-hour system where times from midnight run from 12:00 am to 12:59 am (and not 0:00 am to 00:59 am). It's in ISO 8601.

Comment: @BoarGules OK, but then it's "0-24", not "1-24".

Comment: You can just use the `str.replace` method to replace `'24:'` with `'00:'` so the string becomes parsable by `strptime`.

Comment: @blhsing But the parsed date would be 1 day off.

Comment: @blhsing No you can't, that introduces a 24h error.

Comment: @deceze If you don't have minutes in your times (and OP doesn't, at least according to his question) then there isn't any time with an hour zero.

Comment: @BoarGules Never mind. It is then best to use `strptime` to parse the date part of the string into a `datetime` object, and use regex to extract the time part of the string and construct a `timedelta` object with hours, minutes and seconds, and add the `timedelta` object to the `datetime` object.

Comment: @deceze Alternatively and more easily, replace `'24:'` with `'00:'`, test if there is `'00:'` in the resulting string, and if there is, add `timedelta(day=1)` to the `datetime` object produced by `strptime`.

Comment: And now we're all just spitballing based on little to no information…